# Cutting raster data in R

Tags: r, geospatial, r-raster

I have an interesting case to solve, as I don't have that much experience with this type of data I am asking for some help.

I have about 1000 TIF files, each over 30MB. Every of those files has at least one house roof I am interested in. I would like to cut from the tif only some specific locations based on a file where I store lon lat data. I managed to plot the tif file but I am struggeling to plot the lon lat points. As a next step I would like to cut of only the area near the point. Is it possible?

For importing the TIF files I am using **stars**.

```
y <- read_stars('data/file_1.tif')
y_ll <- st_transform(y, "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84")

coordinates(lon_lat_data) = ~lon+lat

plot(y_ll[,,,1], axes = TRUE)
points(lon_lat_data$lon, lon_lat_data$lat, pch=19, col="red", cex=0.5)
```

The above is not working, any idea why?

After plotting the data point, is there a function in raster to extract only the area by the point?

Here you can find the files:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1UCgcqCKHQHc5PsbPv95zEAmQ0qwKoYY0?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Example data (files that ship with R):

```
library(terra)
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)
xy <- spatSample(r, 10, xy=TRUE, na.rm=TRUE)
v <- vect(as.matrix(xy[,1:2]), crs=crs(r))

plot(r)
points(v)
```

In this example the raster and point data have the same CRS. If that is not the case for you, you should always transform the points (exact and lossless), not the raster data.

```
v <- project(v, crs(r))
```

I do not know what exactly you mean wit "cutting data", but you can use `extract` to get the raster cell values for the point locations.

```
extract(r, v)
#   ID elevation
#1   1       325
#2   2       281
#3   3       324
#4   4       353
#5   5       271
#6   6       306
#7   7       332
#8   8       260
#9   9       270
#10 10       280
```

You could also make a buffer around the points, and perhaps use crop.